# Problem with onblur="submit" when using TinyMCE with JEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, jeditable

I'm trying to use TinyMCE together with JEditable, as per [SamSpeak's blog post](http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/6/12/jEditable-TinyMCE-Plugin).
I'm running into a small but annoying problem.

I set onblur="submit" in JEditable's settings. The behavior I expect (and want) is that as soon as the user clicks away from the editor, the editor submits the new data (in my case, to a function).

**The problem is**, this only happens the first time the user clicks away. Any other time that a user clicks on the editor, it only submits when I click the "submit" button.

**EDIT**: After a bit of digging, it looks like the problem is that JEditable puts the "onBlur" event on the textarea created initially, but which gets "hidden" by TinyMCE when doing "mceAddControl".

Not sure how I can fix this, without messing around JEditable's code.

Thanks,
Edan